# VK oauth2 token get using java

Tags: java, api, oauth-2.0, vk

So I am writing a java program that does some basic http post and get requests to the VKontakte API. So far so good. I have all keys and tokens required so far, but am Struggling with one thing:

When I get my oauth2 token, I have to get it through the browser. 
You actually have to call the following url:

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=YOUR_ID&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=token

... which then redirects you and 'prints' the access token **in the address bar**. Now I want to do all of that programmatically.

So far, I have the following:

```
private static String oauth2Token() throws IOException{
    String url = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6046940&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=token";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
//GET TOKEN HERE
    return oauth2Token;
}
```

But I don't know how to continue. If I trigger the Http connection like this, How can I get the address I am being redirected to (e.g. containing the oauth2 token)?